# $z$-transform of $1/n$

Tags: z-transform

How can one calculate the $z$-transform of: 
$x(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ , where $n \geq 1$? I have searched for table entries, then got stuck while trying to do it with the definition of $z$-transform (summation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can gather, by definition, the $z$-transform is the sum
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{z^{-n}}{n}
$$
which just so happens to be the power series of $-\ln(1 - 1/z)$, converging as long as $|z| > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Good Question

$$\frac{u(n-1)}{n} \rightleftharpoons  ??$$

We know that Z transform is defined as :

$$X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(n)z^{-n}$$

$$u(n) \rightleftharpoons \frac{z}{z-1}$$

**By the use of time shifting property**

$$x(n-1) \rightleftharpoons z^{-1} X(z)$$

$$u(n-1) \rightleftharpoons \frac{1}{z-1}$$

***Differentiate the General formula of X(z) with respect to z***

$$\frac{dX(z)}{dz} = -\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}nx(n)z^{-n-1}$$

$$\frac{zdX(z)}{dz} = -\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}nx(n)z^{-n}$$

$$nx(n) \rightleftharpoons -\frac{zdX(z)}{dz}$$

Now we want to find out the Z transform of $$\frac{u(n-1)}{n}$$

$$x(n) = \frac{u(n-1)}{n} \rightleftharpoons X(z)$$

$$n x(n) \rightleftharpoons -\frac{zdX(z)}{dz}$$

$$n [\frac{u(n-1)}{n}] \rightleftharpoons -\frac{zdX(z)}{dz}$$

$$u(n-1) \rightleftharpoons -\frac{zdX(z)}{dz}$$

Means

$$-\frac{zdX(z)}{dz} = \frac{1}{z-1}$$

$$\frac{dX(z)}{dz} = -\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$$

$$\frac{dX(z)}{dz} = [\frac{1}{z}] + [\frac{1}{z-1}]$$

$$X(z) = ln(\frac{z}{z-1})$$

Hence

$$\frac{u(n-1)}{n} \rightleftharpoons ln(\frac{z}{z-1})$$

Now we have some interesting series for natural log

$$\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2z^2} + \frac{1}{3z^3} + ...... = ln(\frac{z}{z-1})$$

For z = 2

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2\times2^2} + \frac{1}{3\times2^3} + ...... = ln(2)$$

For  $$z = i^2 = -1$$

$$\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ...... = ln(2)$$